# How to compare jquery object with text

Tags: jquery, object, compare

I have  a text created with this code

```
var onetitle = jQuery('.pop_desc_title').text();
```

And i have this object created like this

```
jQuery('.infoboxescontainer .mapbox .maptitle .maptitlemain').each(function(){
    var alltitles = jQuery(this).text();
    return alltitles;
});
```

How i can compare onetitle variable and the created object values and do some action in jquery?

Comment: FYI `each()` isn't creating an object, or even an array. It's just changing the `alltitles` variable on each iteration.

Comment: so how i can compare these 2 values please?I have tried but no result

Comment: what's in `onetitle` and what will be in `alltitles`  ?

Comment: When the values will match i can understand that the item was rendering the second time so I want to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare comparing variable outside of the `each` function so you can access it later. To create an object use the same logic, declare variable outside of the `each` function (to be able to access it)

```
var myObject = [];
var onetitle = jQuery('.pop_desc_title').text(); 

jQuery('.infoboxescontainer .mapbox .maptitle .maptitlemain').each(function(){
    var alltitles = jQuery(this).text();
    if(onetitle == alltitles) { 
        alert(alltitles) // matching title;  
        myObject.push({
          'title' : alltitles
        })
    }
});
console.log(myObject);
```

here i made jsfiddle for this example - http://jsfiddle.net/5buvtw5y/

Comment: How can compare items within the created object and when it will find same titles do some action @Manchary Manchaary?

Comment: And also why in the object were not storing all items?The length is always 1?How i can combine all each results?

Comment: When go with `each` function on the elements with class `maptitlemain`, the function declares EACH element's `text()` to the variable called `alltitles` one by one comparing it with the variable `onetitle`, and if we found match we put the result into the object

Comment: So how i can combine all results of each in one object and compare the created object items?

Comment: hm..you are already comparing each text with a `onetitle`, if you want to compare TWO Objects, create the Object with all the values using each function, then outside of it compare it with the other object

Comment: am new on creating objects could you help me to create that object with all each found results please?

Comment: as i said, on `each` function we get elements one by one and do staff with it. To collect the data from listed elements with class `maptitlemain` into the object, First we need to declare global variable to be able to access it later, outside of the `each` function, do this `var = myObject;`, inside of the `each` function `each(function() { myObject.push ( $(this).text() ) }` we are adding values to an object one by one, after that you can compare it with the other object... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: So am talking about the other object and how I can combine all that results ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94296/discussion-between-manchary-manchaary-and-anahit-dev).

Comment: This exact question was 'how to compare `onetitle` with the values of `maptitlemain`, the question you are asking now is  'how do i compare two objects using jquery'

Comment: Hey @Manchary Manchaary how i can add soem attribute to matched element? I have tried like this `jQuery(alltitles).addClass('matched');` but it didint work. Any ideas?

Comment: There reason it didnt work because 'alltitles' is just a string with a text. Here check this jsfiddle, where added one more variable with an object which contains matched text - http://jsfiddle.net/5buvtw5y/1/

Comment: Yes it works thank you very much for the answer @Manchary Manchaary

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.Here is the code example

```
 var onetitle = jQuery('.pop_desc_title').text(); 
           var item = jQuery('.infoboxescontainer .mapbox .maptitle .maptitlemain');
              for (var i = 1; i <= item.length; i++) {
               if (jQuery(item[i]).text() == onetitle) {
               jQuery(item[i]).addClass('thisClass');
                jQuery(item[i]).parent().parent().remove();
                jQuery('.errorboxalreadyclicked').fadeIn();
                jQuery('.errorboxxlosealreadyclicked').click(function(){
                  jQuery('.errorboxalreadyclicked').fadeOut();     
                });
               }
              }
```